# Linq: splitting a string length and storing the result using a list

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq and am re-factoring some of my old code over to Linq. I have a small problem that I solved using the foreach loop that stores each 250 char's to a list. It would be good to rewrite this using linq, but it seems to not be working. Can someone shed a little light on this?

Code to be refactored:

```
        string comment = "This can be however long but needs to be broken down into 250 chars and stored in a list";
        char[] charList = comment.ToCharArray();
        int charCount = charList.Count() / 250;

        List<string> charCollection = new List<string>();
        string tempStr = string.Empty;

        foreach (char x in charList){
            if (tempStr.Count() != 250){
                tempStr = tempStr + x.ToString();
            }
            else {
                if (tempStr.Count() <= 250)  {
                    charCollection.Add(tempStr);
                    tempStr = "";
                }
            }
```

Not so good attempt with Linq:

```
IEnumerable<string> charCat = System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(comment, n => n.ToString().Length() => 250);
```

Comment: Add `using System.Linq` at the top of the file to be able to use it as extension method.

Comment: thanks Tim, I have that, I can probably take that out of my code.

Comment: So you want a `List<char>` which contains all chars of a string? Simple: `comment.ToList()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, he wants to break his string up into 250 character-sized chunks and store those chunks in a list(that's what I got out of it at least).

Comment: but I would like it broken down to each element only being able to hold 250 chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
List<string> chunks = 
    comment
        // for each character in the string, project a new item containing the 
        // character itself and its index in the string
        .Select((ch, idx) => new { Character = ch, Index = idx })
        // Group the characters by their "divisibility" by 250
        .GroupBy(
            item => item.Index / 250, 
            item => item.Character, 
            // Make the result of the GroupBy a string of the grouped characters
            (idx, grp) => new string(grp.ToArray()))
        .ToList();
```

See the documentation for [`.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information on those methods.

In general, I think the [101 LINQ samples on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) are a great resource for learning LINQ.

Comment: That does everything I need, can you point me in the direction of material I can use to ramp up to write my code like this? Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sure, I'll add some notes to the answer. Glad I could help!